# printf : Is this safe?

Tags: c, printf

I am just wondering if this expression is safe :

```
int main (void)
{
  char my_tab[256];

  memset(my_tab,0x61,sizeof(my_tab));

  printf("Is it safe ? : %.256s",my_tab); /* is it safe ? */
}
```

Comment: If `0x61` corresponds to a "safe" character (I suggest using `'a'` instead), it is safe -- not every computer out there uses ASCII :)

Comment: You are right, I used 0x61 only to get something different from '\0'

Comment: To really be safe you need to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Also, for even more safety, you might want to terminate the string to be printed with a newline: `printf("Is it safe ? : %.256s\n", my_tab);`; and, assuming the code may be compiled with a C90 compiler, add `return 0;` before the final `}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will print out 256 characters, and nothing more.

From the C11-Standard 7.21.6. p4:

> An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to
>   appear for the d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions, the number of digits
>   to appear after the decimal-point character for a, A, e, E, f, and F
>   conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for the g and G
>   conversions, **or the maximum number of bytes to be written for s
>   conversions.** The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed
>   either by an asterisk * (described later) or by an optional decimal
>   integer; if only the period is specified, the precision is taken as
>   zero. If a precision appears with any other conversion specifier, the
>   behavior is undefined.

7.21.6.1. p8:

> s :
>   If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type. Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. If the
>   precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written. If the
>   precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall
>   contain a null character.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced.  Supposing the implementation does `strlen()` to find out how long the string is?  So it should be safe, but might not be.

Comment: @JeremyP If my implementation does that then I'll be wanting my money back!

Comment: @JeremyP: The question is about `printf()`ing not `strlen()`ing, isn't it?

Comment: @JeremyP This is what standars says about s: *If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
element of an array of character type.280)Characters from the array are
written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. If the
precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written. If the
precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall
contain a null character.*

Comment: @JeremyP Therefore imo the null terminator is not needed if you have precision.

Comment: @alk But printf() doesn't happen by magic, there is C code in it that *might* call strlen().  Anyway, I've just checked C99 and the discussion of `%s` says *If the precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall
contain a null character* so the code is safe.

Comment: @2501: The citation in your recent comment is the relevant one, more so than 7.21.6p4. IMHO it should be part of your answer. (I was going to post it as an answer myself, but you beat me to it.)

Comment: @JeremyP: No, `printf` doesn't happen by magic. It happens by the execution of code that is required to satisfy the requirements given in the standard. If an implementation of `printf` calls `strlen` on a `char*` value that doesn't necessarily point to a string, then that implementation is buggy.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe.

From printf(3) - Linux manual page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html :

> ```
>    s      If no l modifier is present: The const char * argument is
>           expected to be a pointer to an array of character type
>           (pointer to a string).  Characters from the array are written
>           up to (but not including) a terminating null byte ('\0'); if a
>           precision is specified, no more than the number specified are
>           written.  If a precision is given, no null byte need be
>           present; if the precision is not specified, or is greater than
>           the size of the array, the array must contain a terminating
>           null byte.
> ```

Function **vsnprintf** in **/lib/vsprintf.c** call *strnlen(s, spec.precision)* to get the lenth of the string to be formatted:

```
/**
 * strnlen - Find the length of a length-limited string
 * @s: The string to be sized
 * @count: The maximum number of bytes to search
 */
size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t count)
{
    const char *sc;

    for (sc = s; count-- && *sc != '\0'; ++sc)
        /* nothing */;
    return sc - s;
}
```

Only the valid char bytes will be accessed.

```
static noinline_for_stack
char *string(char *buf, char *end, const char *s, struct printf_spec spec)
{
    int len, i;

    if ((unsigned long)s < PAGE_SIZE)
        s = "(null)";

    len = strnlen(s, spec.precision);

    if (!(spec.flags & LEFT)) {
        while (len < spec.field_width--) {
            if (buf < end)
                *buf = ' ';
            ++buf;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (buf < end)
            *buf = *s;
        ++buf; ++s;
    }
    while (len < spec.field_width--) {
        if (buf < end)
            *buf = ' ';
        ++buf;
    }

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: The fact that a particular implementation of `printf`, `of `vsnprintf`, or of `strnlen` happens not to choke on an argument that doesn't point to a null-terminated string is relevant only for that particular implementation. The important point is that the C standard requires it to be safe. A particular implementation of `strlen` might be well behaved given a null pointer argument, but `strlen(NULL)` still has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be safe. Implementations that try accessing the character past the end of the buffer should be considered invalid.

Pseudocode for processing `%.Ns`, where `N` is a number, should look as follows:

```
size_t count = 0;
size_t N = ...;
char *ptr = <next-arg>;
while (count < N && *ptr != '\0') {
    putchar(*ptr++);
    count++;
}
```

Note that the above code will never reference the character past `N`.

One could imagine an implementation which inverts the condition of the `while` loop, which would access the byte past the end of the buffer. However, such implementation would be invalid, because according to the standard it is legal for an implementation to require a null terminator only if the size is not specified, or it is greater than the number of characters that you have passed:

> [7.19.6.1.8] If the precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall contain a null character.

Comment: There's a nice standard name for "`output_to_buffer`": `putchar`. :-)

Comment: @R.. Thanks! I guess I should replace my `<next-arg>`, too. It would no longer be a pseudocode, though :-)